# Can I send multiple SMS to multiple recipients simultaneously with showing the MFMessageComposeViewController UI view

Tags: iphone, sms, message, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios5

‪In my iPhone application‬ I want to send test message-the user needs to be able to select multiple contacts and send a text to each one simultaneously?
Means multiple ‪recipients‬ with ‪multiple‬ Sms body and send ‪simultaneously‬.
Can it is Possible with help of ‪MFMessageComposeViewController‬ .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by setting the `recipients` property of the `MFMessageComposeViewController‬` just before you show it to the user. The `recipients` property is an array of phone numbers that the message will be sent to.

Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for help but I am also use the recipients Array.

Comment: Oh! I think I didn't understood your question the first time. But now I get it. You want to send different SMS messages to different recipients without showing the UI anymore right? Well that's not possible. Just think of how apps could have sent SMS messages from your phone without even asking you. That would have been a major security hole.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I want to send different SMS messages Body to different recipients simultaneously with showing the UI.
Can this is possible with another API ?

Comment: @MihaiFratu answered that - you can't use Apple APIs to send different bodies. If you want to do something like that, try a service like: http://www.twilio.com